# Home Page getting error when try add product in cart Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, home-page

I have created my custom theme in magento and designed `default.xml` as per  my requirement, everything is working fine but getting error when trying add product in cart from home page, also minicart not updated .
Please take a look on attached screen-shot

[image]

Comment: Just check your js code . If its not reading any property then check given id and class is it proper ?

Comment: Can you please add your custom code here?

Comment: Hi Mukesh , I have Written whole default.xml custom inside in my custom theme, I create my own header and footer , But i did not understand why i am getting this error .

Comment: @KaushalSuthar I created a custom theme and there are lot of code which is custom which code you want to review , kindly tell me then i can send that.

Comment: Only product add to cart related code...

Comment: @KaushalSuthar I did not create custom code for add to cart functionality, I call widget latest products on hompage .